# How to make pages slide down on click without refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamic

Basically, I would like this websites (http://darynjohnson.com/Medical%20Futures/index.php) pages to slide down from the top of the screen when a link is clicked and slide up when clicked again (preferably without the browser refreshing).

Does anyone know the simplest way of achieving this?

Comment: Sorry about that, I should've read the question better. I would go for the toggle thing

Comment: you need put all pages to one html page, and use jQuery tab logic for page transitions like this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645081/jquery-how-to-create-simple-tabbed-content/11645184#11645184). Next time **try** something for better answers.

Comment: @barlasapaydin I did search but I do not wish to have all content on one html page - read the question

Answer (score 1):

Use JQuery's toggle() function

Comment: Does that work with pages though, or does that just work with divs sliding down?

Comment: You could do an ajax request to grab the content of the other pages. By keeping your pages separate still viewable by URL, you can help browsers without Javascript capability to view your site as well.

Comment: Ah okay. Is slidedown an Ajax animation?

Answer (score 0):

For a smooth transition you should indeed do an AJAX request. Then, use slideToggle or just slideDown to slide the page down.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this functionality http://www.greepit.com/notify/# only you need to do is make it call on load of the page instead of clicking on the different button(like sticky bar, floated bar etc.) you can also make custom css and design as per your requirement.

Hope this will help.