# content change on the div when onclick/hover li tabs

Tags: jquery

i'm trying to achieve the below functionality using jquery.

Example: On this page http://www.adorama.com/pages/FSE-state?mode=state (bottom of the page and above footer) on hovering the side tab the content change on the div

i'm seeing multiple solutions like :eq and #id's

```
<div id="categoryWidet">
     <ul>
       <li>Category 1</li>
       <li>Category 2</li>
       <li>Category 3</li>
     </ul>
     <div>Category 1 content</div>
     <div>Category 2 content</div>
     <div>Category 3 content</div>

</div>
```

can anyone please suggest to one solid solutions.

thanks!!

Comment: Where is your javascript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery how to create simple tabbed content ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645081/jquery-how-to-create-simple-tabbed-content)

Comment: I think this gives me a better idea..http://jsfiddle.net/vRqcb/11/ thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple implementation that grasps the main idea.

http://jsfiddle.net/fenderistic/L2cz3/

HTML

```
 <table border=1>
   <tr>
       <td id=c1>content 1</td><td rowspan=3><div id=c>content1</div></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td id=c2>content 2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td id=c3>content 3</td>
   </tr> 
 </table>
```

JS

```
$( "td" ).hover(function() {

  $("#c").html($(this).html());

});
```