# Strategy for Hiding Visible Elements

Tags: jquery, if-statement

When a user clicks on a `btn` and makes a `tab` visible, I need to find a way to close any `tabs` that might be already visible in the DOM, preferably before fading in the new `tab`.

I've looked into using an `if` statement but can't quite get the logic right.

```
<a href="btn-1">Btn1</a>
<a href="btn-3">Btn2</a>

<div id="tab-1">Content1</div>
<div id="tab-3">Content2</div>




$("[href^='btn-']").on("click", function (e) {
    var $activeTab;
    e.preventDefault();
    $activeTab = '#tab-' + this.href.split('-')[1];
    $($activeTab).fadeToggle("fast");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YMVxq/

I've tried using ":visible" in an if statement, but didn't get the correct results.

I thought about creating an `array` and adding any active tabs to that array, and then popping the array whenever a new button was pressed... sounds overly complicated.

Comment: Would be more readable/easier if you wrap relative elements in some containers to make any transversal method more consistent.

Comment: [Here is a perfect working tab answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11645184/2260614)

Answer (score 2):

Use `siblings()` to hide other divs which are in visible

Try this

```
$("[href^='btn-']").on("click", function (e) {
    var $activeTab;
    e.preventDefault();
    $activeTab = '#tab-' + this.href.split('-')[1];
    $($activeTab).fadeToggle("fast").siblings('div').hide();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YMVxq/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)** to get the sibling `div` of current visible div and hide it:

```
$($activeTab).fadeToggle("fast").siblings('div').hide();
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YMVxq/2/)**

---

Above code should work, however it'll hide all the `div` element which is the sibling of current visible div. It's better to hide only the div whose `id` start with `tab-`:

```
$($activeTab).fadeToggle("fast").siblings('[id^="tab-"]').hide();
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YMVxq/4/)**

Comment: The timing feels strange to me. I'm fading in an element, *then* fading out its siblings. Looks great in production! Thanks Felix.

Answer (score 0):

You could use index but better would be to redefine your HTML markup to use some relevant container:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YMVxq/5/)

```
$("[href^='btn-']").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $activeTab = $('.content').eq($(this).index("[href^='btn-']"));
    $('.content').not($activeTab).slideUp('fast',function(){
        $activeTab.slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

Using here `slideUp/slideToggle`. You could use instead `fadeOut/fadeToggle`

Answer (score 0):

**Simple solution**
*HTML*

```
<a href="#tab1">Btn1</a>
<a href="#tab2">Btn2</a>

<div id="tab1">Content1</div>
<div id="tab2">Content2</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('.active').hide().removeClass('active');
    $($(this).attr('href')).fadeIn('slow').addClass('active');
});
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YMVxq/7/)