# How to make tab switch using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to make tabs switch using jQuery?

Here is what I need. When I click on a link on the left (see the image) I need to change content on the right.

[image]

That is when I click **Marketing** I need to do this following functions:

- remove class active from **stratergy and its contets **
- then add class active to **marketing and its contents**

**Here is the source code**

```
<ul class="marketing_box padbot30 padtop30">
     <li class="scroll_btn active "><a href="#tabs-1">Strategy</a> </li>
     <li class="scroll_btn "><a href="#tabs-2">Marketing</a> </li>
     <li class="scroll_btn "><a href="#tabs-3">Operations</a> </li>
     <li class="scroll_btn "><a href="#tabs-4">Organisation</a> </li>
     <li class="scroll_btn "><a href="#tabs-5">CorporateDevelopement</a> </li>
</ul>

<span class="active" id="tabs-1"></span>
<span  id="tabs-2"></span>
```

**goto this link for live demo** http://theteamconsultancy.com/services.html#service-1

**edit: i have found half myself**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('.acordian ul li ').click(function(){
        $('.acordian ul li ').removeClass('active')
       $(this).addClass('active');
});
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build simple tabs with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645081/how-to-build-simple-tabs-with-jquery)

Comment: The code you posted is not enough/incomplete for us to give you the exact answer. **Or much better if you can provide a jsfiddle/live demo**.

Comment: goto http://www.theteamconsultancy.com/services.html#service-1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.marketing_box li').click(function() {
  $('.scroll_btn').removeClass('active');
 $(this).addClass('active'); 
});
```

Comment: adding to this, to show/hide the correct tabs:
1. add class to the tabs: 

`<span class="content-tab" id="tabs-1"></span>
<span class="content-tab" id="tabs-2"></span>`

And then add the following:
`$('.content-tab').removeClass('active');
var tabId = $(this).attr('href');
$(tabId).addClass('active');`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".scroll_btn a").click(function(event){ //find <a> inside <class="scroll_btn"> and do something when it's clicked
  event.preventDefault(); //Stops any normal click action
  $('.active').removeClass("active"); //I suppose your active class css holds "display: block" and all #tabs-n are set to display:none by default.
  var letsShowThisOne = $(this).attr('href'); //Retrieve your link location - this is actually the ID of the next element we need.
  $(letsShowThisOne).addClass("active"); //Again, i suppose just adding this would do it, but I dont know your css.
}
```

I'm not sure how the rest of your code works, and you didn't put up any jsfiddle, so I just went with my assumptions and tried to do something that should work in your example. Every line is commented to explain what it does.

This will change the content if your css is set up as it seems in your example. It will not change the button. for that add

```
 $(this).addClass("active");
```

Warning though, you're using the class "active" on both buttons and the content. Make sure there's no css conflict and you should be fine. The content is supposedly hidden when "active" class is missing, while the button's "active" class seems like it just adds some extra styles to it.

Comment: `$('.active').removeClass("active");` will remove the class from all elements in the document, not only the tabs/links.

Comment: You're right, if he's using this class name on even more elements on the website, not just the buttons and the content, he should definitely edit that selector.

Answer (score 0):

Hope below code work for you

```
    $('.marketing_box li').click(function () {
    $('.scroll_btn').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var $id = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    $('span[id*="tabs-"]').removeClass('active');
    $('span'+$id).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.acordian ul li ').click(function(){
        $('.acordian ul li ').removeClass('active')
       $(this).addClass('active');   
     var $id = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    $('.prod_tab span[id*="tabs-"]').removeClass('active');
    $('.prod_tab span'+ $(this).find('a').attr('href')).addClass('active');


});
});
```

**working but there is a jumping**