# Buttons that allows to different contents

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently working on my personal website, and I'm now trying to create buttons that would allow me to display different text about the same subject. I order to be more precise, here are two images :

[Button Text 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mp5xx.png)

[Button Text 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHKNi.png)

So when the button "informations" is active, the text displayed is about all the informations that I have to describe the project, and when "credits" is active, the text displayed is more technical (a list). Both text need to be displayed at the same place.

I'm currently devlopping my website on my own using boostrap, and I don't know where to look for a solution (HTML/CSS) or a script (Javascript).

Please let me know if you need more informations to give me the right answer!

Thank you in advance

Comment: Isn't it a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645081/how-to-build-simple-tabs-with-jquery)?

Comment: These are typically called tabs, even though they're styled as buttons. Since you're using bootstrap, there's a [component](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) for that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Bootstrap tabs: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

If you prefer, you could also use jQuery: https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you're using [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), you could use the [tab](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) component, code example below:

```
<div>

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#image1" aria-controls="image1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Image 1</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#image2" aria-controls="image2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Image 2</a></li>

  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="image1">
      <h1>Image 1!</h1>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="image2">
      <h2>Image 2!</h2>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

You would of course replace the content of the two tabs with your own content :). I've placed in two headers (h1) in there as an example.

Note; I am assuming you're using [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) version 3.*.

Comment: Thanks everyone,

I finally made it using the boostrap's tabs!

Comment: Upvote the correct answers and accept the best one then? :)

Comment: By using the up arrow and green tick :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not try bootstraps Collapsible 
   Collapsible

Lorem ipsum dolor text....