# How to call a function inside an html hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, hyperlink

Okay, I've scavenged quite a few questions on here and I've taken what I could from those but it still seems to not be working. (I am fairly new to JavaScript/jQuery.)

Here is the jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5ffhoqpt/1/

```
var showPhotography = function () {
    $(".design").hide();
    $(".film").hide();
    $(".web").hide();
}

var showDesign = function () {
    $(".photography").hide();
    $(".film").hide();
    $(".web").hide();
}
var showWeb = function () {
    $(".design").hide();
    $(".film").hide();
    $(".photography").hide();
}

var showFilm = function () {
    $(".design").hide();
    $(".photography").hide();
    $(".web").hide();
}
```

I'm trying to get each link to show only the div's with the corresponding class, and the other ones should be hidden. (I realize now I have forgotten to show the corresponding class to the link name, but that won't fix my issue)I click the link and nothing will be hidden at all and there's no errors in the console so I really don't know where to begin troubleshooting.

The solution must not include #tags as I need the class to be reused on multiple different sections and containers. I also have other working javascript on my site so the linking of jquery can't be an issue. It must be something else within my code preventing all of the working solutions below to work on my site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build simple tabs with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645081/how-to-build-simple-tabs-with-jquery)

Comment: I'm getting errors with your jsfiddle

Comment: @JoeLissner tried that method out on my site but again, nothing happened when I clicked the "tabs"/<a>

Comment: @adam-beck that's because I can't get it to work and don't know how to solve the issue. Issue being nothing happens when I click the links.

Comment: @JDM_trash you said "and there's no errors in the console". Are you building with jsfiddle? Or are you just using that as a platform to ask your question?

Comment: @adam-beck I used it to share the code faster and in a more convenient form, not building it. You would think the console would give some sort of error but it just must be not recognizing any sort of task for it to do at all.

Comment: @JDM_trash instead of `href=""` try `href="#"` and see if you are seeing any console errors then. The problem may be that when you don't have that it "refreshes" the page and would clear any errors you may be seeing.

Comment: @adam-beck still nothing in the console :/ thanks for your help

Comment: Yeah then without more code I don't think I'll be able to help. I can get this working in jsFiddle by including jquery and changing the load type to `No wrap - in <head>` (which both can be changed in the JavaScript settings which is the gear icon in JS panel)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5ffhoqpt/6/

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

[Full demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jondion/mm5rqy0c/1/)

`<a href="" data-action="showPhotography">Photography</a>`

```
var showPhotography = function () {
        $(".design").hide();
        $(".film").hide();
        $(".web").hide();
    }

var showDesign = function () {
    $(".photography").hide();
    $(".film").hide();
    $(".web").hide();
}
var showWeb = function () {
    $(".design").hide();
    $(".film").hide();
    $(".photography").hide();
}

var showFilm = function () {
    $(".design").hide();
    $(".photography").hide();
    $(".web").hide();
}

var actions = {
    showPhotography: showPhotography,
  showDesign: showDesign,
  showWeb: showWeb,
  showFilm : showFilm
}

$("[data-action]").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var action = $(this).data('action');
  actions[action]()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function toggle_visibility(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  if(e.style.display == 'block')
    e.style.display = 'none';
  else
    e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="" onclick="toggle_visibility('Photo');">Photo</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="" onclick="toggle_visibility('Design');">Design</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="" onclick="toggle_visibility('Web');">Web</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="" onclick="toggle_visibility('Film');">Film</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div id="Film" style="display: none;">
    <p>
        Film Stuff
    </p>
</div>

<div id="Photo" style="display: none;">
    <p>
        Photography Stuff
    </p>
</div>

<div id="Web" style="display: none;">
    <p>
        Web Stuff
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use id and move click event into jQuery

```js
$("#someId1").click(function () {
 $(".design").hide();
 $(".film").hide();
 $(".web").hide();
});

$("#someId2").click(function () {
 $(".photography").hide();
 $(".film").hide();
 $(".web").hide();
});
$("#someId3").click(function () {
 $(".design").hide();
 $(".film").hide();
 $(".photography").hide();
});

$("#someId4").click(function () {
 $(".design").hide();
 $(".photography").hide();
 $(".web").hide();
});
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="" id="someId1">Photography</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="" id="someId2">Design</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="" id="someId3">Web</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="" id="someId4">Film</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="film">
  <p>
    Film Stuff
  </p>
</div>

<div class="photography">
  <p>
    Photography Stuff
  </p>
</div>

<div class="Web">
  <p>
    Web Stuff
  </p>
</div>

<div class="Design">
  <p>
    Design Stuff
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the anchor text can be equal (case sensitive) to the corresponding div class a simple solution can be:

```js
// on document ready
$(function() {
  // for each anchor...listen click event
  $('a').on('click', function(e) {
      // prevent default action: link --> goto another page or...
      e.preventDefault();
      // hide all div
      $('div').hide();
      // show current div
      $('div.' + this.textContent).show();
  }).eq(0).trigger('click');
  // get the first div and simulate the click event in order to start with all hidden except the first div...
});
```

```html
<!-- include jQuery library before using....  -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="">Photography</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Design</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Web</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Film</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div class="Film">
    <p>
        Film Stuff
    </p>
</div>

<div class="Photography">
    <p>
        Photography Stuff
    </p>
</div>

<div class="Web">
    <p>
        Web Stuff
    </p>
</div>

<div class="Design">
    <p>
        Design Stuff
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with jquery at all, mostly javascript, so looking at the jquery I'm not able to figure out what exactly the function does. In the "run code snippet" it works perfectly, but when I copy your jquery into my scripts and then test it on my website I'm working on, nothing happens. Is there something more I should be adding the the javascript? I changed all the words to be completely lowercase to be sensitive to case.

Comment: @JDM_trash Comments added to jQuery code. It can be a good idea starting from there in order to learn what each jQuery method/selector does.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
<a href=javascript:function(args);>Link</a>
```

This approach is far from perfect, but is nice for a quick fix.