# How to display output of multiple buttons on same page using ajax and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, button

i am trying to show output of the button on the same page, after googling i have realized that it is possible with jquery/ajax method. what i really want to do is available on this website http://iptv-station.com/channels/
when we press any button then result is showing on same page. i have tried using ajax method but when i press any button it shows entire items in a file.i don't know much about ajax because i am newer to ajax/jquery. so i have just adjust my code as per my mind. any help is really appreciated. here is what i have tried:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "page.txt", success: function(result){
$("#div1").load("page.txt #p1");
$("#div2").load("page.txt #p2");
    }});
  });
});
</script>
<body>

<button>Button1</button><button>Button2</button>
<div id="div1"><h2></h2></div>
<div id="div2"><h2></h2></div>

</body>

in my page.txt
<p id="p1">Button1 content.</p>
<p id="p2">Button2 content.</p>
```

Comment: the process on that website isn't ajax . the data is loaded in few invisible tabs and when you click on each button , the old tab will be invisible and the new tab will be visible for you .
so what do you want to do ? you want to use ajax or store data at first ?

Comment: thanks for quick response. i don't want to use ajax because i have no sufficient knowledge about it. would you please elaborate how store data works?i want to use store data at first method for this purpose.

Comment: so if yo don't want to use ajax , it's just simple jquery tabs . [Read This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645081/how-to-build-simple-tabs-with-jquery)

Comment: exactly what i am looking for.. thanks a lot @Abolix

Answer (score 0):

as i understand you want to get a content using ajax in a div when you click on button check this example

```js
  $("#a").on('click', function(e) {
  alert("dd");
$.ajax({
    url:'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js', 
    async: false,
          success: function(data){
        alert(data)
           $('#aa').html(data);
        }
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="a">get contenet</button>
<div id="aa"></div>
```